# About infinite summation of $\tau$ function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I prove the following identity:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\tau(n)}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n-1},$$

where $\tau$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$ ?

I haven't made any significant progress. Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First expand each summand on the right-hand sum using the geometric series and see that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n-1} = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-1/2^n} = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty   \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{nk}}.
$$
Now how often does each term of the form $1/2^m$ appear? Once for each divisor of $m,$ thus $\tau(m)$ times - which completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\tau(n)\over 2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d|n} {1\over 2^n}.$$
Now reverse the double sum