# Question involving series of divisor function and Euler function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-counting-function

We shall prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{d(n)}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\phi(2^{n+1}-1)}$, where d(n) the divisor function.
I was thinking of making use of the fact that d(n) is bounded by power of 2, which power is $\Omega(n)$ the number of the prime divisors with the multiplicities of n...
Any ideas?

Comment: no its actually n^2

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2534350

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I found it using the excellent formula searching tool approach0.xyz

Comment: I wonder where you have found this formula

Answer (score 0):

To generalize, we may consider setting $q>1$ so that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge1}d(n)q^{-n}
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^{-n}\sum_{n=ab}1=\sum_{a\ge1}\sum_{b\ge1}q^{-ab} \\
&=\sum_{a\ge1}{q^{-a}\over1-q^{-a}}=\sum_{a\ge1}{1\over q^a-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

This means that the problem is solved as long as we can show that $\phi(2^{n+1}-1)=2^n-1$. I hope this can help you.